# TFS vsts to git repo migration

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I am new to VSTS version controlling, I have one project into TFS 2017 into VSTS version controlling, this project is huge and having all dependencies, moreover we have nested solution ( one .sln contains more than one other .sln into it).

Now I wanted to migrate my VSTS repository into git under TFS 2017 only.

How can i do that? please provide your suggestions

Comment: What do you mean by vsts version controlling ? Are you talking about tfvc ? VSTS has two version control systems in it, tfvc and git

Comment: Do you use TFS 2017 Update 1 or higher?

Comment: @Harshil, it is tfvc

Answer (score 0):

If you use TFS 2017 Update 1 or higher version, import a Git repo from VSTS to TFS is easy. Please follow the steps below:

1. [Create a PAT (personal access token) in VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/_shared/personal-access-tokens)
2. Go to your VSTS repo (`https://account.visualstudio.com/_git/teamproject`), and clone the repo:

[image]

3. Create a Git team project in TFS 2017, go to the repo, and from the repo drop-down, select **Import repository**:

[image]

4. Type the URL you cloned from VSTS (Step2), and type the PAT you created in VSTS (Step1):

[image]

If you use TFS 2017 RTM, you would need to [manually import a repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository#manually-import-a-repo), we suggest you upgrade your TFS 2017 to the latest edition for better experience.

More information of importing a git repo, please refer to the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-git-repository

Comment: Thanks for your input, but in my case I have Repo on tfs on tfvc, and I want to migrate it into git repository

Comment: Do you mean you have migrated your repo from VSTS to TFS tfvc, and want to migrate from TFVC to Git? Or you have your source code in VSTS TFVC?

Comment: It seems you have repo in VSTS tfvc. If this is the case, you can migrate from TFVC to GIT in VSTS first, but the imported repository and associated history (if imported) cannot exceed 1GB in size, and you can import up to 180 days of history, check this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-from-tfvc

Comment: Thanks @Dong, actually we already have on premises TFS, in which we are using tfvc as version controlling, now we want to migrate all repos into git ( provided by TFS) on premises only. Issue is we are having complicated project structure and size of repo is more than 1 gb.

Comment: Since you do not meet the requirements to use this tool, you can use the Git-TFS tool to perform the migration, or perform a manual migration. Check this article: https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/